# UIScrollView view by view scroll on iPad using Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, ios7, storyboard

I have a UIScrollView sample app(uses XIB) where each view will be scrolled page by page just like photo albums, when i create a new iPad application using storyBoard in iOS7 same code is behaves diffrently in the sense when swiped scrollview keeps scrolling it doest stop view by view.

Do i have change some settings in my scrollview any help appriciated.

Comment: try to set paging property of UIScrollview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable paging property in `UIScrollView`. Please read this [tutorial](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/).